# How to convert a sum and product constraint into SMT-lib2 (for Z3)

Tags: constraints, z3, solver

I'm wondering what the best way to convert a sum a le

[image: sum]

or similarly a product

[image: product]

into an SMT-lib2 expression, specifically for solving with [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) (or even [metitarski](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Arith/)).

I thought there would be an obvious approach with a quantifier, but I'm having trouble creating it, and in many use cases such a sum is likely to have constants for `exprLB` and `exprUB`, which would mean that I would hope some kind of tactic would simply unroll it into a long sequence of addition, where use of a quantifier might make that much more difficult.

For example, a fairly trivial tactic to convert

[image: sum from 1 to 3]

into

[image: linearized]

which is both trivially expressed as (and trivially solved by most SMT solvers) as

```
(+ 
  (/ 2 x1)
  (/ 2 x2)
  (/ 2 x3)
)
```

[yielding](https://www.rise4fun.com/Z3/hnk)

```
sat (model (define-fun x1 () Real 1.0) (define-fun x2 () Real 1.0) (define-fun x3 () Real (/ 1.0 4.0)) )
```

How can I generally express a sum over three expressions (lower-bound, upper-bound, and accumulator) elegantly in smt-lib2?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious choice would be to use arrays for your *x* values, and recursive-functions to model the sum/product.

Z3 does support recursive functions, but it's not fool-proof. At best you'll get `unknown,` since most such formulae would require inductive proofs; something SMT-solvers are not good at. At worst, you get an unhelpful answer, or maybe even a bogus one if you hit a bug.

Here's an example that works out ok:

```
(declare-fun xs () (Array Int Real))
(define-fun-rec sum ((lb Int) (ub Int)) Real
   (ite (> lb ub)
        0
        (+ (select xs lb)
           (sum (+ lb 1) ub))))

(declare-fun lb () Int)
(declare-fun ub () Int)
(assert (= (sum lb ub) 12.34))
(check-sat)
(get-value (lb ub xs))
```

Z3 responds:

```
sat
((lb 0)
 (ub 0)
 (xs ((as const (Array Int Real)) (/ 617.0 50.0))))
```

This is pretty cool actually, though maybe not as impressive as you expected. You can force it to a certain range as well:

```
(declare-fun xs () (Array Int Real))
(define-fun-rec sum ((lb Int) (ub Int)) Real
   (ite (> lb ub)
        0
    (+ (select xs lb)
       (sum (+ lb 1) ub))))

(declare-fun lb () Int)
(declare-fun ub () Int)
(assert (= 1 lb))
(assert (= 3 ub))
(assert (= (sum lb ub) 12.34))
(check-sat)
(get-value (lb ub))
(eval (select xs 1))
(eval (select xs 2))
(eval (select xs 3))
```

This produces:

```
sat
((lb 1)
 (ub 3))
0.0
(- (/ 121233.0 50.0))
2437.0
```

Which is a correct model. Unfortunately, slight changes to the formula/assertions cause it to produce unhelpful answers. If I try:

```
(declare-fun xs () (Array Int Real))
(define-fun-rec sum ((lb Int) (ub Int)) Real
   (ite (> lb ub)
        0
        (+ (/ 2.0 (select xs lb))
           (sum (+ lb 1) ub))))

(assert (= (sum 1 3) 12.34))
(check-sat)
```

Then I get:

```
unknown
```

As solvers mature in their support for recursive functions, you can surely expect them to answer more queries successfully. For the short term, you're more likely to see `unknown` responses quite often.

Personally, I think using an SMT solver when you don't know how many terms you have in your sum/product is just not the best idea. If you know the number of terms, by all means use an SMT solver. If not, you're better off using interactive theorem proving, i.e., systems that allow you to express recursive functions and inductive proofs; such as Isabelle, Coq, and others.